# Client id for Google place API

Tags: ios, google-places-api, clientid

I want to use Google places API for my web application. I filled the
form with my Publisher Adsense Id but I didn't receive any email from
Google containing client ID for my use. Is Google places API open for
use now and how can I get this client ID?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to go to [the Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and log in with your Google account. After that click on **API access**, and from there you will be able to create your own public client ID.

Comment: This has changed recently with the new layout they have introduced. You now have to go to ^^"Your project" -> "APIs & auth" -> "Registered apps" -> "Register App"(big red button) -> ^^"Your App" -> "OAuth 2.0 Client ID". (^^ means you have created the name for this field.)